# android activity start/stop order

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question that might look academic, but I have faced in in practice. Let's have an app that comprises two activities `A` (root) and `B`.

`A` -> `startActivity(A.this, B.class)` -> `B` -> `finish()` -> `A`

I have added Log message to `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods of these. When I return from `B` to `A` using `finish()` I get:

05-29 18:48:03.559: D/MYLOG(7075): A starts

05-29 18:48:03.919: D/MYLOG(7075): B stops

As you can see, there's 360ms interval between A starts and B stops. But this interval can be arbitrarily large. I have an app where this interval is about 10 seconds. So I have a time interval when `A` is active and `B` is dying but still alive. What would happen if (in the interval) I start `B` again using `startActivity(A.this, B.class)`?

My real situation is even more complicated because `B` is a `NativeActivity` for an OpenGL game and my app just crashes in C++ code because the game does not expect to be restarted before being finished.

Anyway, at first I would like to know what Android gurus think about my basic question, namely: what happens when one tries to start a "dying" activity?

Comment: Please not that your Activity is not killed. It is paused (and may be destroyed if Android needs resources). Therefore starting it again will just cause to call onResume on B

Comment: The easiest way to know is... just try it. Learning by doing is always good

Comment: i expect `Activity B` will be created again since it was `finish()`ed, but perhaps that isn't the case. Perhaps a solution to your problem is to start cleaning up your native resources in onStop() since that is guaranteed to be called when another Activity takes focus on screen.

Comment: I had the same problem with registering and closing camera. I wasn't able to open camera again when activity restarted too soon, since it wasn't closed yet.
I solved it by writing the cleanup code in onPause. You may also try it and you may need to save instance state.
When you restart activity, the first one will be finished properly.

Comment: @Karakuri No. B.onStop() is not called yet when A appears on screen. And this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to "start a 'dying' activity" as you put it.

Calling `startActivity(A.this, B.class)` after `finish()` in B just creates a new instance of Activity B.

Also one thing to note is that `onStop()` in no way indicates the Activity is dead or dying. See below that from `onStop()` that  `onRestart()` is one possible next step. You should review the [Android Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[image: Android Lifecycle]

If there is an issue such as code in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` that needs to be run in order I suggest you move it elsewhere.

Comment: It's probably more that some of the native processing logic needs to be protected against having multiple instances which could be in different states.

Comment: Well, if the Android lifecycle doesn't allow you to use your currently designed logic the way you want it to, then you'll have to refactor the code so that your processing logic exists either entirely within an Activity lifecycle or exists without a dependancy on an Activity. Without knowing your logic if it 'needs to be protected against having multiple instances' then use the Singleton design pattern for it or some sort of static access.